# Problem rendering additional scenes

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, scene

I'm relatively new to blender since Dec 2020. Using Blender 2.91
I'm currently working on an animation , which I’ve split over 5 scenes.
I made a new scene each time by making a Full Copy of the previous one, the doing the next 300 odd frames.
When I came to render the scenes, it shows nothing, just a grey chequered pattern.

I did notice that with each new scene it created a new camera , i.e. camera.001 , camera.002 etc. SO I made sure I had that camera set as the active camera for the rendering
Also I changed the start and end frames for each scene ie 1-250, 251-700 etc

latest thing ive tried,
I
nstead of just trying to render out the individual scenes, I took the last scene which has all the animations from theprevious scenes in it.
When I try and render out the animation I notice two things.

The first scene frames 1 to 210 render out really quickly , obviously using the png’s from a previous render
As soon as it hits frame 211 I just get the checkered pattern in the render window

I hope someone can help or suggest something I can try

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out the issue.
It’s a user error rather than a blender issue.
I found that when I created the first copy I had a clip in the video editor, which then got copied across to the new scenes.
I didn’t spot it because I’d deleted the clip from the video editor after I’d made the scenes.
Soon as I removed the clip , then the renders started working again.

Interesting lesson learnt lol